# Specifying number of hacking attempts performed on home PC

Tags: security, backtrack, kali-linux

While reading about SSH https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys one thing caught my eye:

*My computer - a perfectly ordinary desktop PC - had over 4,000 attempts to guess my password and almost 2,500 break-in attempts in the last week alone.*

How does author of this article know how many hacking attempts were there on his/her PC?

Comment: records of unsuccessful login attempts in system log?

Comment: How? The author of that article said how in the second sentence of the article. I quote "If you don't think it's important, try logging all of the malicious login attempts you get for the next week." seems pretty clear to me.  The service seems to glaze over the fact most of the services uses to attempt to access a home system are not even required, and thus can be disabled, until they are needed.

Comment: You're totally right - don't know why I missed that. I better go and make myself a cup of coffee. Cheers.

Comment: And note, of course, that the guy is talking about an SSH server, which is, necessarily, exposed on the web.  A computer safely behind a firewall (with no "holes" left open for SSH, et al) will not experience this.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I was suspecting this isn't an ordinary PC but wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: @user1317553  You asked how do you log. Who are you saying is 'totally right'? smc, who says to check the system log?  or ramhound who says " try logging all of the malicious login attempts you get for the next week"   smc's response looks more useful, but did you find the system log? If so perhaps you should answer your own question.

Comment: scm's and Ramhound's answer is exactly the same and they're both right. I wasn't looking for any system the log. Just wanted answer to my question and this has been provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security software and logging systems for each service.  SSH has a simple text log you can examine and count fails.  If you need to handle ssh in linux fail2ban is your friend.

Some logging systems have nice graphical interfaces and they will show you fails in nice graphs.